# Problem with uploading big files with Laravel to S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm stuck with this specific problem for two days and can't find a solution.

So I have Laravel 7.0 project hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which is running fine. I also have S3 bucket, used for saving uploaded videos, which are uploaded to server via user form.

The problem is, smaller files(< 10 MB) are uploaded without a problem. But once it comes to bigger files, `Storage::disk('s3')->put('videos/lorem.mp4', fopen($request->file('file'), 'r+'));` method returns `false` and file is not uploaded to S3. If I use `'public'` disk instead of `'s3'` disk, file is uploaded without a problem.

I also tried to upload file manually via AWS CLI with the same IAM user and it was uploaded without a problem.

PHP and nginx configuration are correctly configured to accept big files.

I know that this is very specific question, but if anyone have a hint or solution, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a timeout  issue on the upload. Increasing the PHP's `max_execution_time` might help. I'd try that first.

Else, you should look into uploading to local disk and have an entirely different process for picking up the files from disk and uploading them to S3. I was amazed at how much throughput you can gain from this [lab](https://github.com/aws-samples/maximizing-storage-throughput-and-performance). It's also worth checking out the [job queues](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) feature in Laravel.